# VideoJs / Javascript | Captions not working

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am using VideoJs but I got a problem with caption - subtitles...they are not working can someone please help me to fix it..here is the [example](http://movieyeland.com/PlayerTest/)
please help me :/

Comment: your example does not work...

Comment: @Gael I had opened adblock detection...fixed now..please help me out..

Answer (score 3):

The error logged to the js console is `{name: "ParsingError", code: 0, message: "Malformed WebVTT signature."}`, i.e. the file is not a valid WebVTT captions file. Your captions file is an SRT file.

Although similar, there are differences between the SRT and WebVTT formats. Specifically in your case you'll need to add the 'WEBVTT' header and change the decimal points in the time codes from `,` to `.`.

```
WEBVTT

0
00:00:05.100 --> 00:00:05.500
*S

0
00:00:05.500 --> 00:00:05.900
*Su
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Web_Video_Text_Tracks_Format

Comment: Its there a way to make it work with srt files too like other videojs versions...I edited the file not working again :/

Comment: If I use 4.11 version subtitles working fine the caption setting its not available...I just want this caption setting to 4.11 or make this one work with subtitles but I don't know how to...thanks for helping me

Comment: SRT did work with video.js up to to 4.11 (although not by design) as they're similar formats. The track parsing is now better but also stricter, so you will need to use true WebVTT files moving forward.

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://openload.io/f/szf8hixQ674/Just_a_Test) its working fine with srt and any other file and also can run srt from pc and url...how is that possible

Comment: Some clever stuff going on there. Rather than have video.js load the captions file, they're parsing the file independently, creating a text track on the player with [addTextTrack()](https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#addtexttrack-kind-label-language-), and adding their parsed cues to that track with [track.addCue()](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/semantics.html#dom-texttrack-addcue).

Comment: Do you know how they do it? and how you find them...I am not good with javascript :/ can you please help me to create a player like their...I just want run srt from pc and url...thanks for your time

Comment: I got the videojs error "Text Track parsing errors". Changing the dots to commas solved it. Thanks a lot for pointing this out.